# Insert array into binary tree item-by-item [PYTHON]

Tags: python, arrays, tree, binary-tree

I have an array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and I want to insert all elements in to Binary Tree item by item, so it would look like this:

```
            1
          /   \
         2     3
        / \   / \
       4   5 6   7
```

I have class Node (representing each node):

```
class Node(self):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value= 0
        self.parent = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

and class Tree (representing the tree itself):

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
```

Now I need to make function which takes an array as the argument and makes the binary tree as I described above.

I've managed this:

```
def insert(array):
    size = len(array)
    tree = Tree()
    insert_node(tree.root, array, 0, size-1)

def insert_node(tree, array, index, size):
    node = Node()
    if index < size:
        node.value = array[index]
        insert_node(node.left, array, index*2 +1, size)
        insert_node(node.right, array, index*2 +2, size)
    tree = node
```

I think something like that could work, but I have no idea how to set 'parent' attribute correctly and how to assign Node to Tree.

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 def insert(array):
        size = len(array)
        tree = Tree()
        tree.root = insert_node(tree.root, array, 0, size-1)
        print(PreOrder(tree.root))


def insert_node(tree, array, index, size):
    node = Node()
    if index < size:
        node.value = array[index]
       node.left = insert_node(node.left, array, index*2 +1, size)
       node.right= insert_node(node.right, array, index*2 +2, size
    return node
def PreOrder(self):
    if self is not None:
        print(self.key)
        PreOrder(self.left)
        PreOrder(self.right)
```

This returns:

```
0
None
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Indeed. That's what you've adviced me.

Comment: Maybe something like that? (I edited the code abov) it returns different values. But still not correct. Or rather something like that: return insert_node(node.left, array, index*2 +1, size)

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to `tree` from inside `insert_node`.  Well, you *can*, but it doesn't change the argument.

Instead, you should have `insert_node` return the `Node` it created, so the caller can put it where it needs to go.  This will solve both your parent and tree assignment issues, assuming you assign the value returned from `insert_node` *every* time it is called.

Comment: So you suggest calling `insert_node` like `tree.root = insert_node(tree.root, array, 0, size-1)` while `insert_node():... return node` ?

Comment: Is there another way to interpret what I wrote?

Comment: Well, I tried to print resulting tree using in_order. And it really didn't return what I expected.

Comment: Seeing neither your code, what you expected nor what you got, I guess you're on your own.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry about that, I totally forgot. I add the code below.